# Javascript: call a function defined in a variable without eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a jQuery plugin that hooks to scroll and drag events, and rotates an element to point towards another element when a relevant event is triggered. Basically my plugin just detects the events, calculates the correct angle, and rotates the element accordingly using a third-party plugin. For a better explanation, you can see the [demos of my plugin](http://pointat.idenations.com/demo/).

I don't want to force a certain rotation plugin to be used, so the rotation function's name may vary. At the moment I'm using eval to allow for custom function names, but I'd like to find another way of doing this. I've tried googling, but so far haven't found a solution.

So, is there a way to get around this? The rotation function's name is stored in settings.rotateFunction:

```
eval("$(this)." + settings.rotateFunction + "(angle)");
```

So far I've tried the "new Function(codeToEval)" method, but this for some reason breaks the use of $(this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript object members (properties or functions) can be accessed using these two notations:

- `object.memberName`
- `object["memberName"]`

The second one is especially useful when member isn't known during design-time but rather during runtime. That's why you can call your rotate function this way:

```
$(this)[settings.rotateFunction](angle);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use following syntax:

```
$(this)[settings.rotateFunction](angle);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! I'm marking the answer by @Robert as the correct answer for being a bit more verbose.